# Align Text and Icons

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm trying to align the text and the icon to be vertically aligned in my navbar. I made the icons inline with the text, but any padding that I give to it to separate the icon and text afterwards results in the icon disappearing.

```
function Navbar() {
    return(
        <div className='flex p-2 justify-evenly text-white bg-black'>
            <div className='fixed left-5 top-4 text-3xl font-extralight  text-[white]'>Logo Here</div>
            <ul className="flex">
                <li className="p-3.5 font-extralight"><FiHome className="inline"></FiHome><div className="m-2">Home</div></li>
                <li className="p-3.5 font-extralight"><FiClipboard className="inline"></FiClipboard><div>Projects</div></li>
                <li className="p-3.5 font-extralight"><FiInfo className="inline"></FiInfo><div>About</div></li>
                <li className="p-3.5 font-extralight"><FiLink className="inline"></FiLink><div>Connect</div></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    );
}
```

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaHq4.png)

I tried different display properties but it doesn't seem to mesh well. The only thing that worked for me was hardcoding icons which isn't really fixing the problem.

Comment: You can give the `flex [flex-col]`(https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex-direction#column) class to `li` and wrap text in a `<div>`. That should do the trick

Comment: Instead of adding a screenshot of code , use code blocks in the editor next time so it is easier to get your code fixed by others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use flex inside the list item, and wrap the text with span so it can be aligned the icon; without wrapping it, it will be aligned with beginning of line.

So you need it like this:

```
<li className="flex justify-center items-center space-x-1.5 p-1.5">
 <FiHome />
 <span>Home</span>
</li>
```

Comment: I see where I messed up now. Your suggestion solve it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can add `flex, items-center, gap-[specify the gap here]` classes to the `li` tag.

That's will add the following properties to the `li`:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
gap: [the specified gap];
```

That should work properly.